# QGIS file exported as AutoCAD DXF not visible on the map and loosing attribute table

Tags: qgis, gdal, dxf, autocad

By continuing the thread here:

[QGIS Export project to DXF loses attribute data in AutoCAD](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/439441/qgis-export-project-to-dxf-loses-attribute-data-in-autocad)

I was trying to export my file as the DXF in order to make the attribute table changes yet in QGIS.

Unfortunately, my file isn't shown at all.

I am saving (exporting) the file as usual (without knowledge of the options below).

[image]

But despite file presence in the layer panel, it's gone!

[image]

I've set the same CRS for this one. I used also the Zoom to Layer option. No result.

As it is worst I cannot edit the layer at all.

Is there a chance of making this file work in QGIS? I could provide some attribute table columns from the GeoJSON file I am working on.

I also tried this export via GDAL

https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/5596

but i keeep getting an error:

**DXF Layer does not support arbitrary field creation...**

[image]

Is it the reason why my DXF doesn't appear in QGIS at all?

Comment: There is also a Export DXF in QGIS via  From the Project Menu choose > Import / Export > Export Project to DXF but here is some useful info about the header info. https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/219904/276

Comment: I know, but after using that option I have no attribute table either.

Comment: I don't really understand what your goal/problem is. You talk about exporting to DXF, making change to attribute table, editing layer and not being able to visualise exported DXF (for this last point make sure you check the visibility of the DXF layer on your picture it's not checked). Could you precise your question ?

Comment: The most important for me is keeping data attribute table when saved my file in DXF format

Comment: The thing is DXF is NOT a GIS format and as such can't keep attribute table...

Comment: OK, but is there any workaround to retain these attributes?

Comment: to my knowledge the only solutions for exporting GIS data to CAD with attributes (saved as block or otherwise) are all paid. AutoCad Map3D, FME, maybe ArcGIS.

Comment: Ok, could you elaborate on the FME abbreviation? Is it some kind of software?